# modal popup after post back c#

Tags: c#, model, popup, controls, autopostback

I have one requirement like,

One master page with three image buttons, once clicking on any button it redirect's to appropriate page, in that page(it's requester form) i have placed all controls in one panel control(id="MyPanel"), one link button(MyLinkButton) out side to that panel and one modal popup control(id=MyModalpopup) as target control id=MyLinkButton,popupcontrolid=MyPanel. On this page load i did code (MyModalpopup.show()) to show all controls in modal popup.

every thing is working fine but, i have controls like dropdown,checkboxlist with autopostback=true and these are in updatepanel and for these controls i am binding data from code behind. Now the problem here is the data i am unable to bind and when these controls are postback the modal popup is not visible.

i am using C# and 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is have a hidden field (with runat=server) that has a true/false value that is set when the modal is activated/hidden.

Then during the client-side page-load of the postback, read that value and make the modal hidden/shown appropriately.

The other option would be to figure out how to make those controls work without the auto-postback (i.e. populating the controls via ajax).